# Max and Min Characters

Tags: python

I'm new to python. I am trying to make a generator that requires 3 letters from an input. I need it to only accept 3 letters no more no less. The `if len` i put does not work

```
import random

usernames = int(input("How Many Usernames Are To Be Generated?"))
names = []
for item in range(0,usernames):
    names.append(input("What Is The First Three Letters of The Pupils Name?"))
if len(names) == 3:
    suffixes = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]
    for name in names:
        final = name + random.choice(suffixes)
        print(final)
else (names):
    print("Error! Must Be 3 Characters")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

else requires no condition

```
import random

usernames = int(input("How Many Usernames Are To Be Generated?"))
names = []
for item in range(0,usernames):
    names.append(input("What Is The First Three Letters of The Pupils Name?"))
if len(names) == 3:
    suffixes = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]
    for name in names:
        final = name + random.choice(suffixes)
        print(final)
else :
    print("Error! Must Be 3 Characters")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is names a list?
You have an empty list, name = [] .
Then you add one item to it .

`names.append(input("What ..`

This is why it fails, because the len of names is 1.

Either get rid of the list or check the len of the first item .

`if len(names[0]) == 3`